# Stored procedure Delete

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi i am practicing stored procedures and i need help.
I want to try to use IF. If a select id exists, then i want to delete it.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE HELLO(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM User WHERE ID = _id) 
THEN 
DELETE FROM User WHERE ID = _id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good example of an `if`.  The best logic is:

```
begin
    delete from user where id = _id
end;
```

There isn't a reason for `if` in this case.  You *could* do:

```
begin
    if exists (select 1 from users where id = _id) then
        delete from user where id = _id;
    end if;
end;
```

I wouldn't recommend this.  But, basically, you just need `end if` for the `if` before the `end`.